# Wordpress: Issue registering/enqueueing style sheet

Tags: wordpress

New to wordpress and I can't get stylesheets to load in my plugin. Either that or thier effects are being overridden. This is what I have in my main plugin.php file:

```
function load_pc_scripts() {
    wp_register_style('plugin-style', plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) . 'plugin-style.css');
    wp_enqueue_style('plugin-style');
  }
  add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_pc_scripts');
```

The style sheet is in the same directory but console shows this:

```
plugin-style.css:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
load-scripts.php?c=0&load[]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils&ver=5.1.1:8 JQMIGRATE: Migrate is installed, version 1.4.1
plugin-style.css:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
options-general.php?page=price-compare-settings:1 Unchecked runtime.lastError: The message port closed before a response was received.
plugin-style.css:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

Answer (score 0):

If the console is showing a 404 then enqueue is working, you likely have a typo in the file name or party in one place or another

Comment: I see it now, there is an extra . after the folder portion of the url: http://localhost:3000/wptest2./plugin-style.css?ver=5.1.1. I guess I'll need to strip that out